# Exception Handler not called in C

Tags: c, exception, seh

I am reading about Structured Exception Handling in C. Here is an example code which does not work as expected:

This code is taken from here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ha52ak6a.aspx

```
// C4733.cpp
// compile with: /W1 /c
// processor: x86
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"
void my_handler()
{
   printf("Hello from my_handler\n");
   exit(1);
}

int main()
{
   _asm {
      push    my_handler
      mov     eax, DWORD PTR fs:0
      push    eax
      mov     DWORD PTR fs:0, esp   // C4733
   }

   *(int*)0 = 0;
}
```

This code should print the message, "Hello from my_handler" when the exception is triggered by trying to write to an invalid memory address. However, it appears that the exception handler is not called at all.

I compiled this code and tried debugging it with Olly Debugger. When the exception occurs, I try passing the exception to the application defined exception handler (by pressing, Shift + F9) but it does not get called. I set a breakpoint at the exception handler (first instruction), but it never reaches that section of code.

What might be the reason for this?

Comment: Looks like it is a compiler warning, not a runtime error checking. I don't have windows so cannot check..

Comment: Have you tried to compile your code with `/ZI /MTd` compiler options ?  
In this way, I have got the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue. The reason that it does not work is that my_handler is blocked by the compiler at linked time.
We need either tell the compiler that my_handler is safe, or totally disable safety-checking. So, there are two ways to make it work. (Tried on both MSVC 2008 and 2010)

- Disable the safeseh table by add /safeseh:no at link time.

  ```
  cl /c C4733.cpp
  link /safeseh:no C4733.obj
  ```
- Create a masm file to add my_handler to the SEH table. But [the SAFESEH example on MSN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16aexws6.aspx) did not work on my laptop. I found this solution on stackoverflow to work instead:
  [Custom SEH handler with /SAFESEH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019689/custom-seh-handler-with-safeseh). But we have to create an additional MASM procedure to jump to the external C function.

Comment: Do you absolutely need that MASM file? Can't you just add that assembly code using inline assembly?

Comment: @Calmarius I doubt if inlining works. There is a -safeseh parameter passed to ml.exe, which is not supported by cl.exe. FYI, I compiled the asm using: ml.exe -Fo my.obj -c -safeseh my.asm